# Counting the number of times a word is repeated

Tags: c#, console

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to count the number of times the word "Correct" appears in my program and then display that number in a Console.Readline ("..."); format.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Console.WriteLine ("Q1: Solve: 12 x 3");
        Start1:
        int ans1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (ans1 == 36) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct.");
        } else if (ans1 != 36) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect. Try again.");
        }
        if (ans1 != 36) goto Start1;
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Q2: 18 ÷ 3");
        Start2:
        int ans2 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (ans2 == 6) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct");
        } else if (ans2 != 6) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect. Try again");
        }
        if (ans2 != 6) goto Start2;
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Q3: 13 + 34");
        Start3:
        int ans3 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (ans3 == 47) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct");
        } else if (ans3 != 47) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect. Try again");
        }
        if (ans3 != 47) goto Start3;
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Q4: 6 x 6 x 6");
        Start4:
        int ans4 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (ans4 == 216) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct");
        } else if (ans2 != 216) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect. Try again");
        }
        if (ans4 != 216) goto Start4;
        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Q5: 32 ÷ 4 x 3");
        Start5:
        int ans5 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        if (ans5 == 24) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct");
            Console.WriteLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Well done. You have answered all questions correctly with {0} retries.");
        } else if (ans5 != 24) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect. Try again");
        }
        if (ans5 != 24) goto Start5;
```

Comment: What do you mean "Appears in my program"?  You mean in the source code?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "appears in my program"? Does it mean in some variable or in user input?

//PS: I'm almost sure you meant Console.WriteLine(...) in the end. PPS: Welcome to SO :).

Comment: By appears i mean it is within speech marks (""). I just wanted to know if there was some way to count all the appearances of the word within this format, if that's possible of course.

Comment: PS. And yes, i did mean Console.WriteLine(...), thanks for the correction :)

Comment: It's some sort of math test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to read what your program outputed to know the correct answer count. Just use a variable instead.

```
int correctCount = 0;

int ans1 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
if (ans1 == 36) {
    ++correctCount;
    Console.WriteLine ("Correct.");
}
else if (ans1 != 36) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect. Try again.");
}
...
```

This way you will know how many answers are correct without relying on the output.

BTW: I strongly urge you not to use `goto` for your program flow as it can lead to multiple headaches.